# 3D touch peek and pop hides navigation bar and status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, 3dtouch

Upon launching the view controller, the `UINavigationBar` and `UIStatusBar` both hide momentarily in between touching the view lightly and force touching to bring up the modal view controller.

Here are the three states:

**1. Without tapping**

[image]

**2. When you're lightly tapping**

[image]

**3. When you force touched**

[image]

Why do the status bar and nav bar disappear momentarily on step 2 and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false

 navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
```

**Update :**

```
 override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
return false
 }
```

Comment: Sadly doesn't make a difference!

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was because I didn't set correct `sourceRect` in

```
- (nullable UIViewController *)previewingContext:(id <UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext 
                       viewControllerForLocation:(CGPoint)location
```

And iOS uses whole view frame as a `sourceRect`, and it overlaps navigation bar and status bar.

For example if you use it in tableView or collectionView you should write something like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:location];
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// you need to check if indexPath or cell are nil
CGRect convertedRect = [cell convertRect:cell.bounds toView:self.collectionView];
previewingContext.sourceRect = convertedRect;
// and after that - return needed view controller
```

Swift version:

```
guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location),
      let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else {
    return nil
}
let convertedRect = cell.convert(cell.bounds, to: collectionView)
previewingContext.sourceRect = convertedRect
// and after that - return needed view controller
```